# "Cannot be resolved as a type" problem with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, crud

```
package br.com.agenda.factory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    
    //nome do usuário do mysql
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    
    //senha do banco
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    
    //Caminho do banco de dados, porta, nome do banco de dados
    
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda";

    /*
     * Conexão do banco de dados
     */
    
    public static Connection  createConnectionToMySql() {
        
        // Faz com que a classe seja carregada pela JVM
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        
        //cria a conexão com o banco de dados
        
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, U, PASSWORD);
        
        return connection;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // Recuperar uma conexão com o banco de dados
        Connection con = createConnectionToMySql();
        
        //Testar se a conexão é nula
        if(con!=null) {
            System.out.println("Conexão obtida com sucesso")
            con.close();
        }
            
    }
    
    
    
}
```

I'm trying to create a crud with Java but Eclipse it's pointing troubles with "Connection", "DriverManager" and SQLException, all of them are showing the same error message "... Cannot be resolved as a type" idk why that is happening, can somebody help me please?

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG6vk.png)

Comment: do you need the project to be modular? If yes, please add the content of `module-info.java` to the question

Comment: excuse me, but what is modular?

Comment: the file `module-info.java` contains a module declaration, so making the whole project modular (not sure if that is the official name). Modules were introduced with Java 9: [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) -- By the question in your last comment, you don't need it, so just delete the `module-info.java` file (created automatically by Eclipse if the corresponding option is not unselected)

Comment: (if you want/need modules, you must add `requires java.sql;` to `module-info.java`, since your code is using that module [`Connection` and `DriverManager`] )

Comment: I suspect is not your actual code, since `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` and `System.out.println` have no `;` at the end and thus this code would not compile.  Does your actual code have those `import` statements in it?  (By the way, the Class.forName line has not been needed for many years.)

Comment: NicolasGarcia the module stuff that @user85421 is talking about is completely irrelevant and you should ignore that part. It's not the problem at all.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Are you sure that the `java.sql` module is not required to use the `Connection`, `DriverManager` and `SQLException` classes in an own module (declared by module-info.java)? I can reproduce the same error in Eclipse by not doing "*the module stuff I am talking about*"! What is yours explanation for `import java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.DriverManager`, both standard edition classes, not being accepted by the IDE?

Comment: Ensure the mysql JDBC library is in the class path. And delete `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` - you don't need it.